# Global variable in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, global-variables

I'm using Phonegap to build my app,in first page I'm using $.getJSON to load data and I want to use that object in all other pages. How to do this? I tried assigning it to a global variable in a call back method of $.getJSON but I'm getting it as undefined in next page so can any one help me in this. I have my .js file and I'm loading it in all the pages. I'm calling particular function on $(document).ready() of every page. Declared a global variable at top,initializing it in 2nd page function and want to load that variable in next page $(document).ready().

Comment: Phonegap apps are usually designed to use a single page and either hide/show divs or dynamically load the content for the divs.  This prevents issues with global variables as the page never actually changes.  It also allows for faster navigation.

Comment: But I have to navigate from one page to another as my static pages are all ready and I'm loading data dynamically now. So how to do this?

Comment: According to this post localstorage would be the best way to go:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646947/phonegap-pass-js-data-between-the-pages

Answer (score 3):

you can do something like this,

A.html

```
$.getJSON(function(data){
    localStorage.setItem("getJSONData",JSON.stringify(data));
})
```

B.html

```
var getJSONData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("getJSONData"));
```

if you want to store data for just current session, you can use `sessionStorage`